# numpy vectorize / more efficient for loop

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, vectorization, image-morphology

I am performing erosion on an image. The image has been padded accordingly.
In a nutshell, I have a cross element(+) that I put on every pixel of the image and pick the lowest value for that pixel from pixel above, below, right, left and itself.

It is inefficient and I can't figure out a vectorized version. It must be possible since all calculations are done independently of each other.

```
for y in range(t,image.shape[0]-b):
    for x in range(l,image.shape[1]-r):
        a1 = numpy.copy(str_ele)
        for filter_y in range(a1.shape[0]):
            for filter_x in range(a1.shape[1]):
                if (not (numpy.isnan(a1[filter_y][filter_x]))):
                    a1[filter_y][filter_x] = str_ele[filter_y][filter_x]*image[y+(filter_y-str_ele_center_y)][x+(filter_x-str_ele_center_x)]
        eroded_image[y][x] = numpy.nanmin(a1)
```

basically:

Every pixel in final image = min(pixel, above, below, left, right) from the original image

```
 for y in range(len(eroded_image)):
     for x in range(len(eroded_image[1])):
         eroded_image2[y][x] = numpy.nanmin(str_ele*image2[y:y+len(str_ele),x:x+(len(str_ele[1]))])
```

This is what I now have. Still 2 loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `image` is a NaN-padded array, and you are eroding with a cross-shaped footprint,
you could remove the for-loops by stacking slices of `image` (to effectively shift the image up, left, right, and down) 
and then apply `np.nanmin` to the stack of slices.

```
import numpy as np

def orig(image):
    t, l, b, r = 1, 1, 1, 1
    str_ele = np.array([[np.nan, 1, np.nan], [1, 1, 1], [np.nan, 1, np.nan]], dtype='float')
    str_ele_center_x, str_ele_center_y = 1, 1
    eroded_image = np.full_like(image, dtype='float', fill_value=np.nan)
    for y in range(t,image.shape[0]-b):
        for x in range(l,image.shape[1]-r):
            a1 = np.copy(str_ele)
            for filter_y in range(a1.shape[0]):
                for filter_x in range(a1.shape[1]):
                    if (not (np.isnan(a1[filter_y][filter_x]))):
                        a1[filter_y][filter_x] = str_ele[filter_y][filter_x]*image[y+(filter_y-str_ele_center_y)][x+(filter_x-str_ele_center_x)]
            eroded_image[y][x] = np.nanmin(a1)   
    return eroded_image

def erode(image):
    result = np.stack([image[1:-1, 1:-1], image[2:, 1:-1], image[:-2, 1:-1], image[1:-1, 2:], image[1:-1, :-2]])
    eroded_image = np.full_like(image, dtype='float', fill_value=np.nan)
    eroded_image[1:-1, 1:-1] = np.nanmin(result, axis=0)
    return eroded_image

image = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
image = np.pad(image.astype(float), 1, mode='constant', constant_values=np.nan)
```

yields

```
In [228]: erode(image)
Out[228]: 
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan,  0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4., nan],
       [nan,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5., nan],
       [nan,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., nan],
       [nan, 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

---

For the small example `image` above, `erode` appears to be around 33x faster than `orig`:

```
In [23]: %timeit erode(image)
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.6 µs per loop

In [24]: %timeit orig(image)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 ms per loop

In [25]: 1190/35.6
Out[25]: 33.42696629213483
```

Comment: For a proper image (`scipy.misc.face().mean(2)` I get a more than twofold speedup by stacking (and taking the nanmin) along axis 0 instead of -1.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: Thanks very much for the improvement.